# How can I label and store (n) number of (a) inputs like a1, a2

Tags: c++, storing-data

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int n, a, k; 
main(){
cin>>n;
for(k=1; k<=n; k++){
cin>>a;}}
```

how can I store inputs to use them in future operations, I'm beginner programmer, I'm looking for easiest way for that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What you want is called an array, or a `std::vector`. 
 That said, it sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Please format your code with tabs, it is good to know the good practice ince the beginning.

Comment: You are looking for something like `array` or `vector`.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to read n integers you can use a vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   int n; 
   std::vector<int> vec;    //Better try to use namespaces
                            //Some spaces add clarity
   std::cin >> n;
   vec.resize(n);

   for(int k=0; k<n; k++)   //Define local varibales relative to loop for iterator
   {
      std::cin >> vec[k];
   }

   return 0;      //Always return a code at the finish of the program
}
```

Comment: Please format your code with tabs, it is good to know the good practice since the beginning. 

Comment: dv taken back. Better make comment on that, as OP might miss this tiny change with bad consequences

Comment: btw there is no need for globals and `using namespace std;` is also best avoided right from the start, but well... the worst mistake is gone

Comment: Thank you for the observation @Adrian, I change my code to other better one.

Comment: @MauricioRuiz Excellent! I hope you can forgive the sarcastic nature of my comment!

Comment: "Always return a code at the finish of the program" - `main` is special in that not returning anything is equivalent to returning 0. Some people might consider it good practice to explicitly write that, but it's not necessary.